# Help the community to detect the questions which should be closed

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, closed-questions, community

I mean, we should add some features to help the community to detect illegal question faster, so they'd still be open for less time.

For example, for the users who have more than 3K reputation points, i.e. can vote to close a question, there can be a page which show the new questions that has some votes to close, or that has many down-votes. If those users noticed those questions quickly, those questions will be judged in a much faster manner by the community, and closed if they deserve to.

What's your opinion? What do you think about such a feature?

Comment: The current status quo is a good compromise.  We still get people that demand questions remain open for at least a minimum period of time, and others like you that want them closed as soon as possible.  As long as neither side is completely satisfied, the solution is probably a good compromise... ;-D

Comment: Adam, I don't want to close questions ASAP, I just want the site to be organized ASAP :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The questions might be judged faster, but I don't know that they would necessarily be judged *correctly*.  There's a tendency towards groupthink in online communities.  I don't think we need to give people a place where they can go looking for questions to close as soon as they hit the 3000 reputation barrier.  If you happen to notice a question that needs closed while you're using the site in a normal fashion, just vote to close it.  If it really needs to be closed **right now** flag it for moderator attention.  I think the system works fairly quickly, and more importantly fairly *well* in its current condition.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean we shouldn't get users' attention for questions that have some potential so the users don't do groupthink?

Comment: @Moayad: Yes.  If we had a page that was specifically set aside for "things that need to be closed" then people would be biased toward closing when they visit that page.  (10K rep users already have such a page, but there are far fewer of them, and they've demonstrated a higher level of trustworthiness to the system.)

Comment: That makes sense, thanks. +1 & accepted.

Answer (score 5):

That is a feature already available, and only available, to 10k+ reputation users.

It's important to avoid echo chambers, groupthink, and band wagons, so having an easy to parse list of what's going on in close voting is only given to those that have really spent significant time with the community.